# switch Statement doesn't switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a value that needs to be read. The value is a Hex that I convert to int.
I have several possible values but the switch statement accept all cases.

```
 int messValue = Integer.parseInt(messType,16);
   switch(messValue)
   { 
   case 160 : System.out.println(messType.toUpperCase() + " It's a financial Message request");
   case 161 : System.out.println(messType.toUpperCase() + " It's a financial Message  response");
   case 162 : System.out.println(messType.toUpperCase() + " It's a Reversal message request");
   case 163 : System.out.println(messType.toUpperCase() + " It's a Reversal message Acquirer Repeat");
   case 164 : System.out.println(messType.toUpperCase() + " It's a Reversal message response");
   case 165 : System.out.println(messType.toUpperCase() + " It's a Network message request");
   case 166 : System.out.println(messType.toUpperCase() + " It's a Network message response");
   case 167 : System.out.println(messType.toUpperCase() + " It's a Network message response issuer");
   default : break;
   }
```

here's the output when the input is "A0" :

```
A0 It's a financial Message request
A0 It's a financial Message  response
A0 It's a Reversal message request
A0 It's a Reversal message Acquirer Repeat
A0 It's a Reversal message response
A0 It's a Network message request
A0 It's a Network message response
A0 It's a Network message response issuer
```

Comment: switch cases "fall through" to the next case unless you add a break statement at the end of handling one case.

Comment: Use `break;` at the end of each `case` statement .

Comment: There must be thousands of duplicates to this question...

Comment: Why bother parsing `messType`? Why not just use cases `"A0"`, `"A1"`, etc.

Comment: Unrelated, but ew. Why not use a map?

Comment: Thanks. That worked.

Answer (score 2):

Add `break;` after every last inner case statement